# how to extract PostgreSQL refcursors in ssrs

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, ref-cursor

Can someone pls help in **postgresql** extracting **refcursors** in **SSRS**.
In the query designer I have given as

```
SELECT        *
FROM            est.test_funct(); "fetch" ALL IN "refc";
```

But its not helping me out to see output.
kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Why not make the function return a table instead of a ref cursor? Then you need no special handling

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thank you for your response,but it returns different return sets,based on few conditions. Hence hve to use refcursors